# I get weird value using parsefloat (using jquery)

Tags: jquery, parsefloat

I just started jQuery and I tried to do some little things, but the last thing I did seems to work in a really weird way, here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".Ivente").change(function () 
    {
        var total = 0;
        $(".Ivente").each(function () 
        {
            var numb = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.'));
            total += numb
        });
        $("#ITvente").val(total);
        alert(total);
    });
});
```

So, for the explanations, this code is supposed to pick every value from my Inputs of class "Ivente" (when I change the value of one), to add them to the total var, and then to place it in a input of "ITvente" id.

I got actually 2 inputs for adding values, it works in one way but return me stupid thing in another way, here two cases :

50,10 and 50,02 the total will be 100,12

but if I put

20,10 a,d 20,02 the total is 40,12000000000000005

Anyone has an explanation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: [**What every SO user asking for help with floating point errors should know**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, it was indeed the floating-point problem, it's fixed now.